# Compatibility with cyanogenmod

Tags: cyanogenmod

Is the galaxy s5 compatible with cyanogenmod 11? It is not on the list of supported devices. I am not sure if it is worth it to try. Has anyone else in the community tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not "Officially" supported, but if you take a look at XDA Forum you'll surely find some unofficial builds.
[Here's](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2777265) a link to one